# Should I call PushLocalFrame and PopLocalFrame when I call Java Method From C++?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Question 1:
I have a java class with a static method:

```
class Test {
    static public void show (String value) {
        // dosomething with value 
    }
}
```

If I want call it from c++:

```
jstring value = env->NewStringUTF("Hello, World");
// ExceptionCheck after NewStringUTF.
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(the_jclass, the_jmethodID, value);
// ExceptionCheck after CallStaticVoidMethod.
```

Should I put **PushLocalFrame** before **NewStringUTF** and put **PopLocalFrame** after **CallStaticVoidMethod** to release local references?

Question 2:

I see the declaration of **PopLocalFrame**, it's:

```
jobject PopLocalFrame(JNIEnv *env, jobject result);
```

After reading the jni documents, I still can't understand why PopLocalFrame needs a **result parameter** and a **return value**. Could you give me a example to show it's existence value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I put `PushLocalFrame` before `NewStringUTF` and put `PopLocalFrame` after `CallStaticVoidMethod` to release local references?

In this particular case I don't see the point. You could just use `DeleteLocalRef` to delete your local reference instead of creating a new local reference frame.

> I still can't understand why `PopLocalFrame` needs a result parameter and a return value

Say that you created a new local reference frame with `PushLocalFrame` and you want to delete all local references created on that frame *except* for one reference that you'd like to keep (e.g. you created some object that you want to return from your function).
You achive this by passing the reference you want to keep to `PopLocalFrame`, and the value you get back is a reference to that object within the previous local reference frame (which now is the current one).

Comment: thanks, micheal. In other words, If I NewStringUTF in c++ (and It's not in a java native method implement, so it's will not return to java.), I have the responsibility to release this local reference. Is the value returned from PopLocalFrame may difference to the argument passed in?

Comment: Local references will be deleted for you if/when you return back to Java. However, if the function needs to create a lot of local references or doesn't return back to Java then you should explictly delete the local references you create. The value returned by `PopLocalFrame` may or may not be different from the argument you passed to it. But even if you get the same value back that doesn't mean that nothing happened to the reference (the reference will still have been transferred to the previous local reference frame).