# Passing NewDirectByteBuffer from C++ to Java (JNI)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have this C++ code:

```
char *buffer = new char[100];

/*
*  ...populate this char array with some data...
*/

jobject jbuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, 100);
```

Afterwards, I want to pass this DirectByteBuffer that I have created in C++ to Java.

I have 2 questions:

1. Will `env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, 100)` clear out my data in char array buffer? Is this the correct way of doing this?
2. When will this buffer be deleted? Should I delete it in C++ sometime afterwards or will Java's GC handle it for me?

Comment: 1. No it won't clear it, yes it's alright.  2. The buffer will be deleted when the JVM feels like it, if ever.  The more relevant question is how long you need to keep buffer alive, and the answer is "until no references to jbuffer exist".

Answer (score 2):

```
jobject jbuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, 100);
```

creates a *local reference* to the Java object. It will be marked unused when explicitly released, or if you use [PushLocalFrame()/PopLocalFrame()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193158/should-i-call-pushlocalframe-and-poplocalframe-when-i-call-java-method-from-c), or when the JNI function that allocated this local reference, returns.

After that, the GC will decide to delete the buffer following the same rules as for regular Java objects.